# The fundamental group of $\pi_1 (P \backslash \{ x \})$, where $P$ is a double torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

**My attempt:**

We will use the van Kampem theorem here.

So, we take the double torus in it's "original" form, namely an octagon with directed edges ($a b a^{-1} b^{-1} c d c^{-1} d^{-1}$).

What we do, is to remove a point inside of that octagon.

So now, we want to apply the van Kampem theorem here.

We define as $U_1$ an area within that octagon (which *doesn't* touch the edges), and $U_2$ is an area with covers the edges of that octagon.

So here, we will have:

$$\pi_1 (U_1) \cong \pi_1 (S^1) = \langle \alpha \ | \ \alpha \alpha^{-1} = e \rangle$$

Because the edges are directed, it's simple to find out $\pi_1 (U_2)$

$$\pi_1 (U_2) \cong \pi_1 (\text{boundary of octagon with directed edges}) = \langle a,b,c,d \ | \ a b a^{-1} b^{-1} c d c^{-1} d^{-1} = e \rangle $$

This gives us:

$$\pi_1 (P \backslash \{ x \}) = \langle \alpha, a, b ,c ,d \ | \ \alpha \alpha^{-1} = e, a b a^{-1} b^{-1} c d c^{-1} d^{-1} = e \rangle$$

Did I miss something here? Or is this the correct answer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141153/discussion-on-question-by-anon-the-fundamental-group-of-pi-1-p-backslash).

Answer (score 1):

$$\pi_1 (U_1) \cong \pi_1 (S^1) = \mathbb{Z} = \langle \alpha \rangle$$

$$\pi_1 (U_2) \cong \pi_1 (S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1) = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} = \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$$

$$\pi_1 (U_1 \cap U_2) \cong \pi_1 (S^1) = \mathbb{Z} = \langle \beta \rangle$$

$$\forall \ \beta \in \pi_1 (U_1 \cap U_2) \quad f(\beta) = g(\beta)$$

$f$ is a homomorphism which projects $\beta$ onto the generator of $\pi_1 (U_1)$. $g(\beta$) will give us an arbitrary combination of $a, b, c, d$, so we get:

$$\alpha = \text{combination of }a, b, c, d$$

So there is no relation here.

Thus, we are left with the elements of $U_2$, namely $a, b, c, d$, only (not $\alpha$ because we showed that it's just a combination of $a,b,c,d$). We have no relation here. So we have:

$$\pi_1 (P \backslash \{ x \} ) = \langle a,b,c,d \rangle = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your van Kampen calculation you need to also incorporate $\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)$. Secondly, $\pi_1(U_2)$ depends on the choice of $U_2$.

In fact, you might as well take $U_2 = P \setminus x$ and notice that $U_2$ deformation retracts to the boundary of the octagon (with identifications), ie the wedge of four circles. Therefore $\pi_1(P \setminus x) \cong \pi_1(\bigvee_4 S^1) \cong F_4$, the free group on four generators. If you are not familiar with the last isomorphism, you could apply van Kampen.